# Exclude files with ctags and vim

Tags: vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I am trying to use vim with ctags but I want to exclude files. I added the next line to the vimrc file:

```
au BufWritePost *.c,*.cpp,*.h,*.go,*.py,*.m silent! !ctags -R --exclude="*.symbolsmap.h" . &
```

(trying to exclude all files with suffix of .symbolsmap.h)

but still when pressing Ctrl+] I am jumping to one of the symbolsmap.h files....
Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

(using mac... if it matters...)

```
> ctags --version
Exuberant Ctags Development, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Apr 18 2022, 11:57:30
  Addresses: <dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net>, http://ctags.sourceforge.net
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex
```

Comment: Your command should work as-is. Could you add the output of `$ ctags --version` to your question?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to exclude, exactly? `symbolsmap.h` files or `foo.symbolmaps.h` files? If the former, the value of `--exclude` should be `symbolsmap.h`, without the `*.`, as your current value only matches the latter.

Comment: @romainl - trying to exclude all files with suffix of symbolsmap.h like foo.symbolmaps.h

Comment: Your ctags command works as-is, here, although I would drop the unnecessary quotes. Maybe you have an old `tags` file lying around?

Comment: I deleted the tags file, but it happened again...